# How to select all entries of a user from a database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to make a "top purchaser" module on my store and I am a bit confused about the MySQL query.

I have a table with all transactions and I need to select the person (which could have one or many transactions) with the highest amount of money spent in the past month.

What I have:

```
name | money spent
------------------
john | 50
mike | 12
john | 10
jane | 504
carl | 99
jane | 12
jane | 1
```

What I want to see:

With a query, I need to see:

```
name | money spent last month
-----------------------------
jane | 517
carl | 99
john | 60
mike | 12
```

How do I do that?

I do not really seem to find many good solutions since my MySQL query skills are quite basic. I thought of making a table in which money is added to the user when he buys something.

Comment: You’ll want to look at `GROUP BY` and `SUM`

Comment: Select name , sum( moneyspent) from your_table group by name order by 2 desc;

Comment: Do you have data that on which date the user made the transactions? If yes, then please add schema to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple aggregated query :

```
SELECT t.name, SUM(t.moneyspent) money_spent_last_month
FROM mytable t
GROUP BY t.name
ORDER BY t.money_spent_last_month DESC
LIMIT 1
```

The query sums the total money sped by customer name. The results are ordered by descending total money spent, and only the first row is retained.

If you are looking to filter data over *last month*, you need a column in the table that keeps track of the transaction date, say `transaction_date`, and then you can just add a `WHERE` clause to the query, like :

```
SELECT t.name, SUM(t.moneyspent) money_spent_last_month
FROM mytable t
WHERE 
    t.transaction_date >= 
        DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    AND t.transaction_date <= 
        DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY t.name
ORDER BY t.money_spent_last_month DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This method is usually more efficient than using `DATE_FORMAT` to format dates as string and compare the results.

Comment: How would money_spent_last_month work? What do I put instead of it?

Comment: you don't need the specifier t and you also don't need LIMIT 1.  There's only 1 file that's being accessed once (so no need for t) and the group by will give you 1 record per name